# NullPointerException when opening screen with a webview widget on some devices

Tags: android, flutter, dart, webview, nullpointerexception

When run across 13 devices, one of them (Moto Z with Android 7.0) gives me a NullPointerException on pre-launch tests from Play Console when it opens a screen with the plugin. Strangely it does work flawlessly on every physical device I've tested.

Webview plugin is flutter_inappwebview 2.1.0+1

Is there a way I could catch this error so I would provide another view for the user? The offending widget is inside a scaffold on a return statement from a build method

```
 I/DisplayManagerService(1357): Display device changed state: "flutter-vd", OFF
 I/DisplayManagerService(1357): Display device removed: DisplayDeviceInfo{"flutter-vd": uniqueId="virtual:com.danproductions.medical.guiadebulasf,10148,flutter-vd,0", 1440 x 1744, modeId 2, defaultModeId 2, supportedModes [{id=2, width=1440, height=1744, fps=60.0}], colorTransformId 0, defaultColorTransformId 0, supportedColorTransforms [], HdrCapabilities null, density 640, 640.0 x 640.0 dpi, appVsyncOff 0, presDeadline 16666666, touch NONE, rotation 0, type VIRTUAL, state OFF, owner com.danproductions.medical.guiadebulasf (uid 10148), FLAG_PRIVATE, FLAG_NEVER_BLANK, FLAG_OWN_CONTENT_ONLY}
 I/DisplayManagerService(1357): Display device added: DisplayDeviceInfo{"flutter-vd": uniqueId="virtual:com.danproductions.medical.guiadebulasf,10148,flutter-vd,0", 1440 x 1848, modeId 3, defaultModeId 3, supportedModes [{id=3, width=1440, height=1848, fps=60.0}], colorTransformId 0, defaultColorTransformId 0, supportedColorTransforms [], HdrCapabilities null, density 640, 640.0 x 640.0 dpi, appVsyncOff 0, presDeadline 16666666, touch NONE, rotation 0, type VIRTUAL, state ON, owner com.danproductions.medical.guiadebulasf (uid 10148), FLAG_PRIVATE, FLAG_NEVER_BLANK, FLAG_OWN_CONTENT_ONLY}
 E/NetworkScheduler.ATC(8575): Called cancelTask for already completed task com.google.android.gms/.measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService{u=0 tag="Measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService.UPLOAD_TASK_TAG" trigger=window{start=0s,end=1s,earliest=0s,latest=0s} requirements=[NET_CONNECTED] attributes=[PERSISTED] scheduled=0s last_run=0s jid=N/A status=ACTIVE retries=0 client_lib=GMS_TASK_SCHEDULER-19629000} :1
 V/ConnectivityManager(8575): isActiveNetworkMetered() returns:false
 D/AndroidRuntime(10476): Shutting down VM
 E/AndroidJUnitRunner(10476): An unhandled exception was thrown by the app.
 I/AndroidJUnitRunner(10476): Bringing down the entire Instrumentation process.
 E/MonitoringInstr(10476): Exception encountered by: Thread[main,5,main]. Dumping thread state to outputs and pining for the fjords.
 E/MonitoringInstr(10476): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.Display.getSize(android.graphics.Point)' on a null object reference
    at org.chromium.ui.display.DisplayAndroid.updateFromDisplay(DisplayAndroid.java:133)
    at org.chromium.ui.display.DisplayAndroidManager$DisplayListenerBackendImpl.onDisplayChanged(DisplayAndroidManager.java:169)
    at android.hardware.display.DisplayManagerGlobal$DisplayListenerDelegate.handleMessage(DisplayManagerGlobal.java:462)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

I've traced down by including some debug info and I discovered I get "*webview created*" and progress reaches 100, BUT webview started is NOT shown. When using another device I get "*webview started*" message.

```dart
    InAppWebView(
      initialHeaders: {},
      initialOptions: InAppWebViewWidgetOptions(
          inAppWebViewOptions: InAppWebViewOptions(
            debuggingEnabled: true,
          )),
      onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
        webView = controller;
        print("webview created");
      },
      onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {
        print("webview started");
        setState(() {
          this.url = url;
        });
      },
      onLoadStop:
          (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) async {
        setState(() {
          this.url = url;
        });
      },
      onProgressChanged:
          (InAppWebViewController controller, int progress) {
        setState(() {
          print(progress);
          this.progress = progress / 100;
        });
      },
    ),
```

Comment: What OS versions are on the other devices?

Comment: @tomerpacific 4.4.4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10

Answer (score 0):

I've looked online a bit and found your issue being reported in various places.

[Here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31012)

[Here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30420)

I don't know what version of Flutter you are using, but according to the second link,
the problem originates from a bug in Chromium when there is an orientation change.

Taken from the discussion there, I'd advise doing the following:

`The fix is available starting webview_flutter version 0.3.11+3`

Comment: Is there a way I could catch this error so I would provide another view for the user? The offending widget is inside a scaffold on a return statement from a build method

Comment: @Daniel - you would need to provide some code (as should of been done in the first place) of the area where this crash happens, so we can understand what can be done.

Comment: I'm trying to find the piece of code that is generating the error but since language is Dart I'm finding a bit difficult to discover where does "android.view.Display.getSize" como from.

Comment: @Daniel - By looking at the stacktrace you have provided and reading the fact that you have used a plugin for the webview, it can be difficult to trace where the crash happens. I am guessing that when an orientation change occurs, some lifecycle callback is initiated that triggers logic that causes the crash. I would investigate that. Irregardless, if my answer helped you, please mark it as such.

Comment: Sure, I added the piece of code where the crash happens and provided some debug info.